# looping over columns in a model using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to loop through all the columns of a model and (1) set the value to lowercase and (2) trim it but I can't seem to get the syntax right. This is what i have so far:

`@response.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value|

   @response."#{attr_name}".downcase.strip!

end`

I've searched around and can't seem to find an example of actually setting the value of the model column. All the examples I find deal with displaying the value or field name of each column. In other languages there is an evaluate or eval function to do this but I can't seem to find the equivalent in Ruby.

Comment: `send` is what you're looking for

Comment: That's totally invalid syntax...

Comment: Are you going to downcase created_at and update_id and id?

Comment: @T_Q: Can you state some hash example what do you really want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `write_attribute` method to alter an `ActiveRecord` attribute by name

```
@response.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value|
  @response.write_attribute( attr_name, attr_value.downcase.strip )
end
```

Outside of `ActiveRecord` framework it is common to use the `send` method to call a bunch of accessors by name. That would work here, too:

```
@response.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value|
  setter = "#{attr_name}="
  @response.send( setter, attr_value.downcase.strip )
end
```

However, the authors of ActiveRecord have foreseen this need, and the `write_attribute` syntax would be my recommendation here.

Comment: looks like write_attribute is a private method so went with the send example you posted. Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 1):

You should try this code:

```
@response.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value|
  @response[attr_name.to_sym] = attr_value.to_s.downcase.strip
end
```

Then check @response. It will assign all the values with downcase and stripped in @response variable.